# Webcontent code modified from eclipse not updating

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I have java source code of about 3000 classes & other web content (js, css, html).  I imported the project in eclipse(indigo) and run the project on Tomcat6. After ant **compile.complete.deploy**,  a new folder **${env.CATALINA_HOME}**.
I am modifying few js & html files from IDE, but it doesn't reflect in the browser. I reloaded the page several times, but no changes are done.

In Project -> Buildautomatically option is checked.

Do i need to modify on the files in **${env.CATALINA_HOME}**  or the direct src code is fine?

Comment: After every build i see Webcontent folder  & ${env.CATALINA_HOME}  created.   Of this which file should i modify for code changes in browser. I believe i need not touch both these and modify the source code. Correct me if am wrong, i am new bie to eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the UI related content -   Webcontent folder files needs to be changes.  And when new class files are added or existing classes are modified then  "ant smartbuild" does fine.

--
thanks.